# How to make a DateTime object, with the right timezone?

Tags: php, datetime

I'm working on a WordPress-site, where I'm making some batch-jobs (running in the terminal with commands such as: `php my-batch-job.php`). I've asked previously about how to correct the DateTime, so it's the right timezone, where I'm sitting (Copenhagen), but got a long and good answer on [why the timezone shouldn't be changed in functions.php](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/385653/128304).

But that leaves me a bit puzzled.

Does that mean that I have to run these lines of code, every time I need a DateTime object:

```
date_default_timezone_set ( 'Europe/Copenhagen' );
$datetime = new DateTime();
date_default_timezone_set( 'UTC' );
```

That seems excessive, doesnt' it?

I built it into a static function, but still...

I'm also thinking that it's a lot of extra operations. Let's say that I'm looping 1000 objects and making a DateTime-object for each of them, then the timezone will be swapped back and forth every time.

And are there a smarter way of getting around this, without changing the timezone on the server, which apparently is a big 'no-no'?

Answer (score 1):

[`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) allows you to [modify the time zone of an instance](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php) without having to change the default time zone. The strategy here would be to create [`DateTimeZone`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) instances for both the time zone used by the server when the dates were stored, and the desired output time zone. You can then provide the server time zone to `DateTime` along with the date string when instantiating, then change the time zone on that `DateTime` instance to your output time zone.

```php
<?php

// Some test date-times
$dateTimeStrings = [
    '2019-08-01 00:35:04',
    '2014-06-21 14:43:09',
    '2017-03-09 18:33:04',
    '2014-06-21 14:43:06',
    '2017-03-09 18:33:03',
    '2014-06-21 14:43:05',
    '2012-12-18 02:28:22',
    '2012-12-18 02:28:21',
    '2018-05-13 00:34:20',
    '2016-03-29 10:04:34',
    '2012-12-18 02:28:20',
    '2012-12-18 02:28:19',
    '2018-05-13 00:34:19',
    '2016-11-25 03:53:11',
    '2016-03-29 09:36:36',
    '2013-02-21 05:45:37',
    '2015-02-06 18:50:49',
    '2012-12-18 02:28:18',
    '2016-03-29 08:54:17',
    '2017-03-09 18:32:59'
];

/*
 * Create DateTimeZone instances for our stored time zone, and the
 * desired output time zone
 */
$storedTimezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Copenhagen');
$outputTimezone = new DateTimeZone('UTC');

foreach($dateTimeStrings as $currDateTimeString)
{
    /*
     * Create a DateTime instance from the the stored date and the
     * timezone instance corresponding to the time zone in the stored
     * data
     */
    $date = new DateTime($currDateTimeString, $storedTimezone);

    // Get a formatted representation of the stored date for comparison
    $storedDate = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP');

    // Change the time zone
    $date->setTimezone($outputTimezone);

    // Get a formatted representation of the updated date
    $outputDate = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP');

    // Compare the original and updated date values
    echo $storedDate.' -> '.$outputDate.PHP_EOL;
}
```